# R Programming Negative Binomial Distribution

Tags: r

Why I am not getting same answer while using density function?

```
pnbinom(3,2,.5)
#[1] 0.8125

a=dnbinom(5,0,0.5)+dnbinom(4,1,.5)+dnbinom(3,2,.5)
a
#[1] 0.15625
```

Comment: Why do you expect the same answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think you wanted to do following:

```
pnbinom(3,2,0.5)

sum(dnbinom(0:3,2,0.5))
```

giving

```
> pnbinom(3,2,0.5)
[1] 0.8125
> 
> sum(dnbinom(0:3,2,0.5))
[1] 0.8125
```

(i.e. cumulative probability `pnbinom` is the same as the sum of individual probabilities via `dnbinom`)